# general vs trunk port

Tags: networking, dell-powerconnect

I have inherited a Dell PowerConnect network where the uplinks are set as general switchport and every vlan is tagged on that port. (vlan 1 is untagged on the port.)

Will there be any repercussions if I change the ports to trunk mode or is it a better security practice to keep uplinks as general switchports?

Comment: Certain mfg's follow what you have setup already (for instance Extreme Networks).  Either one should work fine for "switch to switch" connectivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very possibly there will be repercussions, what if the devices on the ports aren't VLAN-tag-aware? Packets will just be dropped. Use both types where appropriate.

Comment: They are switch-to-switch connections. In all cases, the uplinks are connected to a vlan-aware switch.

Comment: That would have been useful to know earlier, in which case you'll be fine.

Comment: Is there any added security benefit to having the ports as general instead of trunk?

Comment: Perhaps but only really on a theoretical basis, there's anecdotal reports of .1q trunk jump hacks but they're not in the wild.